# Web Api net core 2.0 OnAuthorization (own attribute) return 500

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-webapi

I've got some problem when learning Web Api on Net Core 2.0
I have written my own authorization attribute

```
  public class BasicAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var actionContext = context.HttpContext;
            var authService = BasicController.GetService<IAuthenticationService>();
            var authKey = actionContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

            if (authKey == string.Empty || !authService.ApiKeyProperly(authKey))
            {
                actionContext.Response.Redirect("~/unathorized.html");
            }
        }
    }
```

and i'm using it in some action:

```
 public class UsersController : BasicController
    {
        [BasicAuth]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            IUsersService usersService = GetService<IUsersService>();
            var users = usersService.QueryUsers().ToArray();
            return Ok(users);
        }
}
```

My authService check if key is properly and on debug i go to last line of BasicAuthAttributeClass (authorization was ok), but when i press "continue"
i get 500 besides go back to ma UserController. It doesn't goes to GET method after leaving attribute class.

What have i done wrong?
I'm missing something?

I get an error:

```
InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found
```

but what scheme should i add?
 if i do in my Startup.cs (WebApi)

```
services.AddAuthentication();
```

what should i put here?
i dont want use any cookies, etc
i just want change my methods behaviour - if it has an attribute (basicauth)
just check the key.
if key is ok -> get back to method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some ugly, but for me satisfying result ;)

```
 public class BasicAuthAttribute :Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            var actionContext = context.HttpContext;
            var authService = BasicController.GetService<IAuthenticationService>();
            var authKey = actionContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

            if (authKey == string.Empty || !authService.ApiKeyProperly(authKey))
            {
                context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            }

        }
    }
```

so i dont use AuthorizeAttribute but i derive from Atrribute
and then if context.result get some result
no action will be called after leaving method